# Passing data from login controller to frontviewcontroller of SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm sorry for my english.

My question is how to pass a data from a login viewcontroller to frontviewcontroller of the SWRevealViewController library. Let me explain my situation.

My app has a login view. If the login informations are ok you can enter inside the app where the menu would be managed by SWRevealViewController.

This is my storyboard:

[image: mystoryboard app]

To "remember" who is the user that was logged-in i want to pass an ID from the loginview (in my storyboard called "View Controller") to "HomeappViewController".

In my ViewController prepareforsegue method i wrote this code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"entrataApp"]) {
    SWRevealViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    UINavigationController *navViewController = (UINavigationController *) [destination frontViewController];
    HomeAppViewController *destViewController = (HomeAppViewController* )[navViewController topViewController];
    destViewController.testoPassato = risposta;
  }
}
```

And in HomeAppViewControllerthis is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   self.title = @"News";

   // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
   _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
   _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

   // Set the gesture
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

   _datiPassati.text = _testoPassato;
}
```

As you can see i try to pass "risposta" that contain my "user ID" to destViewController.testoPassato that is the label inside HomeAppViewController but when i launch the code the label staies empty.

In your opinion which is my error? Maybe do i need to define homeAppViewController as frontviewcontroller? How can i do that?

I'm sorry if my question is stupid but i'm new in iOS app development.

Comment: Why don't you try to NSLOG your object in your favourable ViewController where you try to pass it.

Comment: Can You share the declaration of your property testoPassato ?? Can you just check if it is set to strong?

Comment: @NKB this is the declaration `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *testoPassato;`

Comment: try adding @synthesize testoPassato;

Comment: what about destination.delegate = self is missing?

Comment: @NKB I'm sorry but `@synthesize testoPassato = _testoPassato;` doesn't improve on the problem.

Comment: @walle84 what do you mean for `destination.delegate = self`? Destination is the controller of the `[segue destinationViewController]` (in this case SWRevealViewController), how can help me set the delegate of destination to self? I'm sorry but i'm new in iOS development.

Comment: Try Changing this , HomeAppViewController *destViewController = (HomeAppViewController *)[destination topViewController];

Comment: @yourwish `NSLog(@"Testo passato è pari a: %@", _testoPassato);` in `homeAppViewController` reports (null)

Comment: Delegate is need to be set in SWRevealViewController. So I would suggest you be to go through demo of [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). Download and understand it firslty. Also I provide you with one more which have lil' more hands than SWReveal ,i.e.,[ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). Vote up if this was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you will need to know who is logged in user through out the application what you can do is to store the user id when user log in from the response of the webservice

you can store that using following

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[dictData valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"uid"];
```

here dictData is my response dictionary and field is id

Further add these to your constant or in your .pch file

```
#define UserId     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"uid"]
```

and then use UserId where ever you need in the application in any viewController in any class.

When you want to provide the Logout Facility in the application give

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

These will remove all the keys and again when you execute the application it will go the login page.

Comment: Great, sounds good!!! I don't know nothing about NSUserDefauld and .pch file, but now i check the topic and try to implement it. But aren't there any problems with this kind of variables that are like "global"? And when the user logout, how can i reset the variable?

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks a lot!!!! A last question: is a good solution set `UserId` to nil before the logout of the user?

Comment: I've been looking for such a solution for days now. Thank you!